# giving an input a dynamic value emeberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

So I have an each loop that iterates over an ember model:

```
{{#each model.product.variants as |variant|}}
    {{input type="radio" value=variant.id name="product_id" action="radioChecked" on="focus-in"}}
{{/each}}
```

What im trying to do is set the value of each input to the `id` of the `variant`, this part right here `value=variant.id`. now this seems like it works because this is an example of the HTML being rendered:

```
<input id="ember821" name="product_id" type="radio" value="34">
```

I removed the extra ember classes from the above input to make it fit in one line.

Now what I'm trying to do is when the form is submitted grab the value of the radio button that is checked. what I did is give the radio button an action, `action="radioChecked" on="focus-in"` and I try to set a `product` property on my controller. here is my controller:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    selectedProduct: null,

    actions:{
        radioChecked: function(){
            console.log('action worked');
            this.set('selectedProduct', value);
        }
    }

});
```

I get the error that value is undefined. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value` is passed in, so you need to define in your function definition.

```
function(value){
     console.log('action worked');
     // note this will just be the id, you may want to query your collection
     // and use the object instead of the id...
     this.set('selectedProduct', value);  
}
```